TypeError: ForwardRef._evaluate() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'recursive_guard'
Pls help. I need help setting up spacy inside jupyter enviornment
I am trying to use spacy to summarize youtube transcripts but finding lots of problems with spacy and python 3.12.4/3.12.3.
I started with 3.12.4, then installed python 3.12.3 onto conda environment py3.12.3.
I install spacy 3.7.6 into env with pip install stacy
Here are the `conda env list: 
base                     /opt/anaconda3
py3.11                *  /opt/anaconda3/envs/py3.11
py3.12.3                 /opt/anaconda3/envs/py3.12.3

I added python kernels via cmd below
jupyter kernelspec install py3.12.3
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=py3.12.3

On command line, import spacy is ok:
(py3.12.3) UID ~ % python           
Python 3.12.3 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, May  6 2024, 14:43:12) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spacy
>>> quit()
(py3.12.3) UID ~ % pip freeze | grep spacy
spacy==3.7.6
spacy-legacy==3.0.12
spacy-loggers==1.0.5


Inside jupyter (run from base, restarted after installing py3.12.3), import spacy gives error below.  Any help is welcomed???
1. (base) UID ~ % python -m ipykernel install --user --name=py3.12.3
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Installed kernelspec py3.12.3 in /Users/UID/Library/Jupyter/kernels/py3.12.3


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import spacy # module will be used  to build NLP model
      2 from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS # module will be used  to build NLP model
      3 from string import punctuation

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py:13
     10 # These are imported as part of the API
     11 from thinc.api import Config, prefer_gpu, require_cpu, require_gpu  # noqa: F401
---> 13 from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
     14 from . import util
     15 from .about import __version__  # noqa: F401

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
      2 from .dep_parser import DependencyParser
      3 from .edit_tree_lemmatizer import EditTreeLemmatizer

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/attributeruler.py:8
      6 from .. import util
      7 from ..errors import Errors
----> 8 from ..language import Language
      9 from ..matcher import Matcher
     10 from ..scorer import Scorer

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/language.py:43
     41 from .lang.tokenizer_exceptions import BASE_EXCEPTIONS, URL_MATCH
     42 from .lookups import load_lookups
---> 43 from .pipe_analysis import analyze_pipes, print_pipe_analysis, validate_attrs
     44 from .schemas import (
     45     ConfigSchema,
     46     ConfigSchemaInit,
   (...)
     49     validate_init_settings,
     50 )
     51 from .scorer import Scorer

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/pipe_analysis.py:6
      3 from wasabi import msg
      5 from .errors import Errors
----> 6 from .tokens import Doc, Span, Token
      7 from .util import dot_to_dict
      9 if TYPE_CHECKING:
     10     # This lets us add type hints for mypy etc. without causing circular imports

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/tokens/__init__.py:1
----> 1 from ._serialize import DocBin
      2 from .doc import Doc
      3 from .morphanalysis import MorphAnalysis

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/tokens/_serialize.py:14
     12 from ..errors import Errors
     13 from ..util import SimpleFrozenList, ensure_path
---> 14 from ..vocab import Vocab
     15 from ._dict_proxies import SpanGroups
     16 from .doc import DOCBIN_ALL_ATTRS as ALL_ATTRS

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/vocab.pyx:1, in init spacy.vocab()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx:49, in init spacy.tokens.doc()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spacy/schemas.py:195
    191         obj = converted
    192     return validate(TokenPatternSchema, {"pattern": obj})
--> 195 class TokenPatternString(BaseModel):
    196     REGEX: Optional[Union[StrictStr, "TokenPatternString"]] = Field(None, alias="regex")
    197     IN: Optional[List[StrictStr]] = Field(None, alias="in")

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py:286, in ModelMetaclass.__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
    284 cls.__signature__ = ClassAttribute('__signature__', generate_model_signature(cls.__init__, fields, config))
    285 if resolve_forward_refs:
--> 286     cls.__try_update_forward_refs__()
    288 # preserve `__set_name__` protocol defined in https://peps.python.org/pep-0487
    289 # for attributes not in `new_namespace` (e.g. private attributes)
    290 for name, obj in namespace.items():

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py:808, in BaseModel.__try_update_forward_refs__(cls, **localns)
    802 @classmethod
    803 def __try_update_forward_refs__(cls, **localns: Any) -> None:
    804     """
    805     Same as update_forward_refs but will not raise exception
    806     when forward references are not defined.
    807     """
--> 808     update_model_forward_refs(cls, cls.__fields__.values(), cls.__config__.json_encoders, localns, (NameError,))

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/typing.py:554, in update_model_forward_refs(model, fields, json_encoders, localns, exc_to_suppress)
    552 for f in fields:
    553     try:
--> 554         update_field_forward_refs(f, globalns=globalns, localns=localns)
    555     except exc_to_suppress:
    556         pass

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/typing.py:529, in update_field_forward_refs(field, globalns, localns)
    527 if field.sub_fields:
    528     for sub_f in field.sub_fields:
--> 529         update_field_forward_refs(sub_f, globalns=globalns, localns=localns)
    531 if field.discriminator_key is not None:
    532     field.prepare_discriminated_union_sub_fields()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/typing.py:520, in update_field_forward_refs(field, globalns, localns)
    518 if field.type_.__class__ == ForwardRef:
    519     prepare = True
--> 520     field.type_ = evaluate_forwardref(field.type_, globalns, localns or None)
    521 if field.outer_type_.__class__ == ForwardRef:
    522     prepare = True

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/typing.py:66, in evaluate_forwardref(type_, globalns, localns)
     63 def evaluate_forwardref(type_: ForwardRef, globalns: Any, localns: Any) -> Any:
     64     # Even though it is the right signature for python 3.9, mypy complains with
     65     # `error: Too many arguments for "_evaluate" of "ForwardRef"` hence the cast...
---> 66     return cast(Any, type_)._evaluate(globalns, localns, set())

TypeError: ForwardRef._evaluate() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'recursive_guard'


Please read how to work with the Anaconda/conda system you opted into by choosing to use it. They have good Getting Started documentation and more that you can read. You should not be using pip unless there is no conda recipe. Sticking with Anaconda/conda will result in more robust and portable environments. Spacy is available, you can see the command here. You need to specifically connect Jupyter to your conda environments. See the top two scored answers here for insight how to do that. ...

 If you do activate Jupyter with the kernel you need in your environment and not base, then you should be able to run that  conda install command I referenced in a cell in the Jupyter Notebook with the magic symbol % in front, so %conda install ... and that can make sure you know you install to the same environment that Jupyter is using. See here for more information about the magic install command that you can use inside a Jupyter cell.

I see from the answer there is a version conflict issue. Despite that, the overarching suggestion I had to actually use the management approaches that Anaconda/conda is meant for remains good advice.

First, tks for the pointers and info!  I believe I did install environments via conda.
Here are the conda env list:
base                     /opt/anaconda3
py3.11                *  /opt/anaconda3/envs/py3.11
py3.12.3                 /opt/anaconda3/envs/py3.12.3
I did add python kernels to jupyter via


Good, but the dependencies/packages should also be primarily installed via conda, too.

Thank you.  Restarted and create conda py3.11 with spacy and several other modules.   got is working in jupyther NB!  Thank you...

Temporary solution is to downgrade python to version 3.12.3
linked gits:
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/9609#issuecomment-2155832461
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/9637#issuecomment-2162571909

Another solution is to:
Update your pydantic version from to v2.7.4, so even if you have Python 3.12.4, it will work:
pip install pydantic==2.7.4

